# Spring Boot can't find database settings using multiple datasources

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get multiple datasources working with spring boot 3, tried hundred changes and can't find way for it to not give this error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')
```

here are the properties

```
logging.level.=TRACE
server.error.include-stacktrace=always
spring.main.banner-mode=off
spring.output.ansi.enabled=always
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
server.port=8080

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
databaseA.datasource.platform=mysql
databaseA.datasource.username=myusername
databaseA.datasource.password=mypassword
databaseA.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
databaseA.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
databaseA.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306
databaseA.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306
databaseA.datasource.hibernate.connection-url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306
databaseA.datasource.hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306
databaseA.datasource.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
databaseA.datasource.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=490
databaseA.datasource.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=490                    
databaseA.datasource.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
databaseA.datasource.hibernate.show_sql=false
databaseA.datasource.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
databaseA.datasource.jakarta.persistence.query.timeout=9000
databaseB.datasource.platform=mysql
databaseB.datasource.username=myusername
databaseB.datasource.password=mypassword
databaseB.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
databaseB.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
databaseB.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306
databaseB.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306
databaseB.datasource.hibernate.connection-url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306
databaseB.datasource.hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306
databaseB.datasource.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
databaseB.datasource.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=490
databaseB.datasource.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=490                    
databaseB.datasource.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
databaseB.datasource.hibernate.show_sql=false
databaseB.datasource.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
databaseB.datasource.jakarta.persistence.query.timeout=9000
```

```
package com.myproject.spring.database;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "databaseBEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "databaseBTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.myproject.spring.repository.databaseB"})
public class DatabaseBDatasourceConfiguration {

       private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseBDatasourceConfiguration.class);   
               
       @Bean(name="databaseBDataSourceProperties")     
       @ConfigurationProperties("databaseB.datasource") 
       public DataSourceProperties databaseBDataSourceProperties() {
           DataSourceProperties props = new DataSourceProperties();
           LOG.debug("databaseBDataSourceProperties : 200 : props = "+props);
           return props;
       }
        

        @Bean(name="databaseBDataSource") 
        @ConfigurationProperties("databaseB.datasource")        
        public DataSource databaseBDataSource( ) { 
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }   
        
        
        @Bean(name="databaseBJdbcTemplate") 
        public JdbcTemplate databaseBJdbcTemplate(
                @Qualifier("databaseBDataSource") DataSource dataSource ) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }       
        
        
        @Bean(name="databaseBEntityManagerFactory")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean databaseBEntityManagerFactory(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder ,
                @Qualifier("databaseBDataSource") DataSource dataSource
                ) {
            return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.myproject.spring.model.databaseB").persistenceUnit("databaseB").build();
        }
        
        @Bean(name="databaseBTransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager databaseBTransactionManager(
                @Qualifier("databaseBEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
        }   
        
        @Bean(name="databaseBDataSourceTransactionManager")
        @Autowired
        DataSourceTransactionManager databaseBDataSourceTransactionManager(@Qualifier("databaseBDataSource") DataSource dataSource) { 
            return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
        }
}
```

```
package com.myproject.spring.database;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "databaseAEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "databaseATransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.myproject.spring.repository.databaseA"})
public class DatabaseADatasourceConfiguration {

        private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseADatasourceConfiguration.class);      

        @Bean(name="databaseADataSourceProperties")
        @Primary        
        @ConfigurationProperties("databaseA.datasource")    
        public DataSourceProperties databaseADataSourceProperties() {
            DataSourceProperties props = new DataSourceProperties();            
            LOG.debug("databaseADataSourceProperties : 200 : props = "+props);
            return props;
        }

        @Bean(name="databaseADataSource") 
        @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties("databaseA.datasource")        
        public DataSource databaseADataSource( ) { 
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();      
        }
        
        @Primary
        @Bean(name="databaseAJdbcTemplate") 
        public JdbcTemplate databaseAJdbcTemplate(
                @Qualifier("databaseADataSource") DataSource dataSource ) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }
        
        @Primary
        @Bean(name="databaseAEntityManagerFactory")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean databaseAEntityManagerFactory(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder ,
                @Qualifier("databaseADataSource") DataSource dataSource
                ) {
            return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.myproject.spring.model.databaseA").persistenceUnit("databaseA").build();
            //return emfBuilder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.myproject.spring.model.databaseA").build();            
        }
        
        @Primary
        @Bean(name="databaseATransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager databaseATransactionManager(
                @Qualifier("databaseAEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
        }
        
        @Primary
        @Bean(name="databaseADataSourceTransactionManager")
        @Autowired
        DataSourceTransactionManager databaseBDataSourceTransactionManager(@Qualifier("databaseADataSource") DataSource dataSource) { 
            return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
        }               

}
```

I am expecting no errors when spring starts up, its able to auto configure 2 different datasources. In this case both mysql but future one can be oracle or postgres. There shouldn't be any general properties that don't map to one datasource or the other

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have decided its too difficult to get information on spring supports basic things like this, so putting spring on back burner